# Error while inserting data to Postgres via python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm executing one python script and i'm getting the below error while inserting the data to PostgreSQL database.Below is the database schema and sample query i use.

Any suggestions on how to deal with it ?

```
 cur.execute(cmd, str(api_response))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Also i would like to add the datetime to the this table, If i have a timestamp in the table schema, How can i insert the current time to the table and what change i need to do?

Below is the sample script.

```
import psycopg2

def db_connect():
 try:
     DSN = "dbname='postgres' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='postgres' port='5432'"
     conn = psycopg2.connect(DSN)
     return conn
 except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
     print('database connection failed')
     quit()

start_dt = date(2020, 10, 1)
end_dt =  datetime.date(datetime.now())

connection=db_connect()

cur = connection.cursor()

cmd="""INSERT into email_stats(raw_data) SELECT %s"""

for dt in daterange(start_dt, end_dt):
  start_date = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
  end_date = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

  try:
     api_response = api_instance.get_aggregated_smtp_report(start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date)
     cur.execute(cmd, str(api_response))
   
connection.commit()
```

Table schema

```
CREATE TABLE  email_stats
(raw_data text COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
WITH (OIDS = FALSE)TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Sample API response

```
    Database connected...
    Cursor initiated
    Connection succesful
    {'blocked': 0,
     'clicks': 0,
     'delivered': 140,
     'hard_bounces': 0,
     'invalid': 0,
     'opens': 7501,
     'range': '2020-10-29|2020-10-29',
     'requests': 4,
     'soft_bounces': 0,
     'spam_reports': 1,
     'unique_clicks': 0,
     'unique_opens': 3502,
     'unsubscribed': 9}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user2/Downloads/bu.py", line 54, in <module>
    cur.execute(cmd, str(api_response))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: For most DB-APIs, parameters must be passed as iterables and not scalars. So pass params in list `cur.execute(cmd, [str(api_response)])` or tuple `cur.execute(cmd, (str(api_response),))`.

Comment: @Parfait Thanks a lot :) Worked . Could you post it as an answer.

Comment: Technically, your question is actually a duplicate, having been asked multiple types with same error. Be sure to [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1422451) before asking.